# Cant find reference in Mongo DB documentation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been struggling with MongoDB documentation for some time now. I want to know what will method returns and their definitions for each field. It's just that it's not on their documentation

For example I want to know what will **db.collection.deleteMany()** returns

The documentation does not tell you what will it return when it succeeded.

To overcome this I thought I can just know it by myself by just returning trying it and return the raw result from the **db.collection.deleteMany()** method

and I there you got the result

```
{
    "result": {
        "n": 32,
        "ok": 1
    },
    "connection": {
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 4,
        "id": 1,
        "address": "127.0.0.1:27017",
        "bson": {},
        "socketTimeout": 360000,
        "monitorCommands": false,
        "closed": false,
        "destroyed": false,
        "lastIsMasterMS": 2
    },
    "deletedCount": 32,
    "n": 32,
    "ok": 1
}
```

But then I realized I don't know what those fields definition

What's `result.n`? What's `result.ok` ? What's `connection._events`?

Am I doing it wrong how will I find those definitions please help thanks

Comment: See [deleteMany](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#deleteMany), 
[deleteWriteOpCallback](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#~deleteWriteOpCallback) and 
[deleteWriteOpResult](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#~deleteWriteOpResult).

Answer (score 0):

I just had to go to the API reference for the particular driver I was using and not to the method references.

For Node.js [here is the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api) for API references.